# Where are the Black Powder Explosives in Savage Worlds?

Tags: savage-worlds

Today, I considered the idea of trying to run a "blackpowder" fantasy setting in Savage Worlds, having been inspired by the video game Darkest Dungeon and its gun-toting, bomb-chucking brigands.

However, while the core rules cheerfully go over things like flintlock pistols and the blunderbuss, and though they have rules for cannons and grenades, I can't find anything regarding early explosives.

The fantasy companion contains rules for siege weaponry, but while they go over cannons and even early flamethrowers, the barrel full of powder tossed in a hole under the hall isn't even mentioned, nor the early hand grenades with the long fuses that you see everywhere in modern cartoons. The same ones that were used from the early Modern Age up until the American Civil War.

My question is: **Where are black powder explosives statted out in Savage Worlds?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 50 Fathoms

You have to dig a bit to find it, but in the gear chapter you'll find a Shrapnel Bomb, rated at 2d6 damage.

> A "shrapnel bomb" is an early form of hand grenade comprising a charge of gunpowder encased in a metal shell designed to fragment on detonation. They cause damage to everything in a Medium Burst Template.

*50 Fathoms* also has has casks of gunpowder used as an improvised explosive. In the **More on Firearms** section of the Gear chapter, you'll find an entry titled Powder as Explosive.

> Every 10 [firearm] shots of gunpowder causes 2d6 damage in a standard Medium Burst Template. A cask of gunpowder causes 5d6 damage in a Large Burst Template. If additional bombs are rigged to explode at the same time, roll their damage separately.

Note that 10 shots is about 1 pound of gunpowder and that each cask holds 100 shots.

Note: I haven't mentioned the price because costs are extremely setting dependent, and the values in *50 Fathoms* are only for that specific setting and its unique economic situation. You'll have to choose costs that make the most sense for your setting.

Comment: While actual bombs were made of clay so that they could actually explode (which would probably lower the cost by a solid deal, removing most of the metal), yes, this is exactly what I was thinking of! Thanks a bunch, mate!